# How to check numbers after decimal point?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I check the numbers after a decimal point?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[1,2,3.5,4,5.8]})
```

df:

```
    num
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.5
3   4.0
4   5.8
```

After check:

```
    num check_point
0   1.0      0
1   2.0      0
2   3.5      1
3   4.0      0
4   5.8      1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) for get values after decimal, then compare for not equal with `ne` and cast to integer:

```
df['check_point'] = np.modf(df['num'])[0].ne(0).astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['check_point'] = np.where(np.modf(df['num'])[0] == 0, 0, 1)
```

Another idea is test if floats without `.0` are integers:

```
df['check_point'] = np.where(df['num'].apply(lambda x: x.is_integer()), 0, 1)
```

Or:

```
df['check_point'] = np.where(df['num'].sub(df['num'].astype(int)).astype(bool), 1, 0)
```

---

```
print (df)
   num  check_point
0  1.0            0
1  2.0            0
2  3.5            1
3  4.0            0
4  5.8            1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (np.modf(df['num']))
(0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.5
3    0.0
4    0.8
Name: num, dtype: float64, 0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
Name: num, dtype: float64)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! You are awesome!

Comment: @DimaFirst - Thank you for interesting question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the diff between the number and its rounded version and determine if it's a int.

```
df['check_point'] = df.num.sub(df.num.round()).ne(0).astype(int)
```